# BIRT - Parâmetro Relatório - Listbox Dinâmico - Selecionar Todos

Tags: javascript, java

Estou criando um relatório no BIRT, onde nos parâmetros do relatório (tela de filtro) tenho um ListBox que é carregado dinamicamente, portanto os dados irão sofrer variações e é inviável deixar o default value com todos os itens selecionados, pois ao ser adicionado um novo registro no dataset terei que alterar o relatório.

Gostaria que ao abrir a tela e carregar os dados, seja automaticamente selecionado todos os itens do ListBox.

Vlw!